# Best way to save data

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I have a raw-data to save as vocabulary in my app, I can save it in `excel db` or `sqlite`, or `xml`, but I can't make a choice of. In future an users can add new items and I need to store them. What is the best storing format for my case?

Comment: you can't be storing something just for the sake of storing them. you will be accessing them in the future too. so i suggest use the method that provide the easiest access of the data

Comment: as per as  data storing is concern you can use any of them , but when it will comes to fetch the data SQLite is the best way to fetch the data in optimistic way

Answer (score 2):

Use a SQLite database. It will provide all the facilities required, and is built into android. Also, XML or excel can't match the speed and query capabilities of SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

I think using `sqlite` is the best, because getting an item from it is easy and smooth.
While in `xml` I'm not sure if it allows to store item in programmatically and same with `excel db`.

ex. in sqlite it's about like this:

```
a.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("users"));
```

so if you are looking for suggestions, I think sqlite is fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case it is good to save data in standard way - using sqlite database.
If user can edit you db, and they will do it often - you can use some ORM implementations for android in your project (greendroid, ormlite etc) they are pretty simple and convenient.